# Showing the circle and contents of TextView in one activity

Tags: java, android

I wrote the following code and I want display the circle and the contents of the **TextView** that it has area of the circle. But when I run the following code, It displays only the circle and It can not display the circle and the contents of **TextView**  together. What is the solution?

**Draw.java**

```
public class Draw extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
Draw(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawCircle(120,120,40,paint);
}
}
```

**Cal.java**

```
public class Cal extends View {
    Cal(Context context){
        super(context);
    }
    public double result;
    double parameter = (Math.pow(40,2)) * 3.14;
    public void cal(){
        result = Math.sqrt(parameter);

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    Draw draw;
    Cal cal;
    TextView textView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle s){
        super.onCreate(s);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        cal = new Cal(this);
        cal.cal();
        textView.setText(""+ cal.result);
draw = new Draw(this);
        setContentView(draw);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

**Done with in single Activtiy**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Draw draw;
Cal cal;
TextView textView;
LinearLayout linearLayout;

public void onCreate(Bundle s) {
    super.onCreate(s);
    setContentView(R.layout.test1);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    cal = new Cal(this);
    cal.cal();

    textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textView.setText("" + cal.result);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    draw = new Draw(this);
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
    linearLayout.addView(draw);
}

public class Draw extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    Draw(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(120, 120, 40, paint);
    }
}

public class Cal extends View {
    Cal(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public double result;
    double parameter = (Math.pow(40, 2)) * 3.14;

    public void cal() {
        result = Math.sqrt(parameter);

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It was useful. But as you can see in the above code, we have a Cal class and it has a value(result variable). I want display this variable with the circle in one activity without significant change in the code.Is it possible?

Comment: u want cal.result add into circle ??

Comment: I want add cal.result on side the circle. but It does not matter much. Only I want display the result variable in activity.

Comment: this way u do canvas.drawText(""+cal.result,90, 120, paint);

Comment: just pass cal.result in canvas drawtext. u set your own drawing view thats why textview is never seen which u r use in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

`textView.setText(""+ cal.result);`  change this line as like below

```
textview.setBackground(cal.result);
textview.setText("your text goes here");
```

(Or)

It is too simple use `<layer-list>` to draw circle and set this as your textview background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="#222222" />

            <size
                android:height="28dp"
                android:width="28dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

you must create .xml file in drawable

Comment: Thank you. But I do not want use .xml file for this.